# Tensorflow creat matrx from its elements and elements' index

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow, tensor

Say, for a N-by-N matrix, only m elements are nonzero. If we already have the m non-zero elements and all their indices (i,j), how to build the matrix in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

Use [tf.SparseTensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensor) and, if required, [tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_tensor_to_dense). For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
indices = [[0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 2], [2, 1]]
st = tf.SparseTensor(indices, values, dense_shape=[3, 3])
dt = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(st)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(dt)
    print(result)
```